# Hive Query in PySpark Application

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark version 2.3.0.2.6.5.0-292

When I'm running this script in client mode, I keep  getting 0 as result
It seems it's not taking the right variables in spark.sql query

```
import pyspark.sql
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sconf = SparkConf().setAppName("AppName")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=sconf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

yesterday = '2020-03-01'
today = '2020-03-02'
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from db.table where cast(inserted_timestamp as string) >= {} 
                and cast(inserted_timestamp as string) < {}".format(yesterday,today))

df.count()
```

Comment: it was for bold characher

Comment: sqlContext.sql("select * from db.table where cast(inserted_timestamp as string) >= {} and cast(inserted_timestamp as string) < {}".format(yesterday,today))

Comment: the result is 0  , it doesn't count yesterday and today

Comment: Are those timestamp columns? In that case change `cast(inserted_timestamp as string)` to `to_date(inserted_timestamp)`. That should do it. This is not a query error. It's simply because you're not filtering the right values.